# what permissions are needed for writing to uls logs?

Tags: uls, ssom

We have creates a webpart and in the catch block we are writing logs to uls.

My concern is regarding permission to write to this log. Will users with read-only access to sharepoint face no issue?

```
 private void WriteToULS(TraceSeverity Level, string OutStr)
        {
            SPDiagnosticsService.Local.WriteTrace(0, new SPDiagnosticsCategory("Portal Error", Level, EventSeverity.Error), TraceSeverity.Unexpected, OutStr, null);
        }
```

I would also like to know if it a good practice to use:

```
private void WriteToULS(TraceSeverity Level, string OutStr)
            {
 SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
                {
                SPDiagnosticsService.Local.WriteTrace(0, new SPDiagnosticsCategory("Portal Error", Level, EventSeverity.Error), TraceSeverity.Unexpected, OutStr, null);
 }); 
            }
```

in the code for all webparts.

Answer (score 1):

Call the below method ,this will ensure you are have correct/appropriate permissions while users with read permissions write to log file.

```
SPSecurity RunWithElevatedPriviledges{
LogData();
}

public static void LogData(string categoryName, Level type, string section, string message, string exception)
{
    try
    {
        /*Log SharePoint*/
        SPDiagnosticsService diagnosticsService = SPDiagnosticsService.Local;
        diagnosticsService.WriteTrace(0,
                                      new SPDiagnosticsCategory(categoryName, TraceSeverity.Unexpected,
                                                                EventSeverity.Error),
                                      TraceSeverity.Unexpected, exception, exception);
    }
    catch
    {
        throw new Exception("ExceptionManager.LogData > Failed !");
    }
}
```

Refer for ULS logs details if required : [where see the log SPDiagnosticsService WriteTrace](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/95042/where-see-the-log-spdiagnosticsservice-writetrace/95046#95046)

Comment: This is what I mentioned :-)

Comment: lol , i didnt see your comment :)

Comment: Hi Nikhil, I tested it out and it seems that the user with only read permission can write to ULS log, it didnt give me any error. I am logging to ULS at every catch block in my webpart code..

Comment: You logged in with user with read access . But SPDiagnosticService will/always use app pool account to write to ULS logs.

Comment: Ok, can you tell me what priviledges should the apppool account (site collection administrator) have if I donot use elevated priviledges?

Comment: Does the RunWithElevatedPreviliges run under the webapplication account or the sitecollection account?

Answer (score 0):

Users with read only access won't be able to write to ULS. Write the code inside RunWithElevatedPreviliges delegate

Comment: I have user with read only permission and I tested it out and can confirm that the user can write to ULS log without using ElevatedPriviledges.. Can you confirm this?:

Comment: Also, the RunWithElevatedPreviliges code runs under the account used during webapplication creation. So unless that user has permission to write to ULS then it will throw error?